# issue in appending rows in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following code that everthing is alright, even the file generated in  "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/4.csv" is correct

```
d <- data.frame()
 for(i in 1:nrow(testresult))
{
b<- pnbd.ConditionalExpectedTransactions(est.params, T.star = testresult     [i,8],
                                 x, t.x, T.cal)

m6<- list(testresult[i,1],b)

d <- rbind(d,m6)

write.table(m6,file="C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/4.csv",     append=TRUE,sep=",",col.names=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)
}
```

I need a data frame similar to  "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/4.csv". That's why I added

```
   d <- rbind(d,m6)
```

to append the new rows to my dataframe. The results for `d` is some repeated rows. Hope I am clear. Please ignore line 4 of the code if they are not clear. They are not the issue.  the issue is only d <- rbind(d,m6)

Comment: Your object `m6` is a `list` and so cannot be attached to a dataframe using `rbind`. It depends on the output from your function `pnbd.ConditionalExpectedTransactions` but what you probably want is to create a vector using `m6 <- c(testresult[i,1], b)`.

Comment: Thanks Zack, it seems you are right,m6 <- c(testresult[i,1], b) works.  I'm happy to accept your answer if you post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer:

Your object `m6` is a `list` and so cannot be attached to a dataframe using `rbind`. It depends on the output from your function `pnbd.ConditionalExpectedTransactions` but what you probably want is to create a vector using `m6 <- c(testresult[i,1], b)`.